# bash: string interpolation

Tags: python, bash

I am returning strings from a python module, for consumption within a bash script.

This is what I have so far:

```
SCRIPT_DIR=/somepath/to/scripts/folder
cd $SCRIPT_DIR/eod

python_cmd='import sys;
            sys.path.append("/somepath/to/scripts/folder/utils"); 
            import settings as st; 
            print " ".join(st.foo())'

# Fix indentation for Python
python_cmd=${python_cmd//'            '/''}

my_array=(`python -c "$python_cmd"`)
```

I want to use the DRY philosophy in the snippet above. However, the string`/somepath/to/scripts/folder` is repeated in the script. I would like to pass the definition of $SCRIPT_DIR into the python_cmd - however I tried (replacing the path string in python_cmd with $SCRIPT_DIR/utils and it failed with the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 3, in <module>
ImportError: No module named settings
```

What am I doing wrong?

**Note:**

I am running bash 4.1.5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't bother to pass the string in at all.  Instead of modifying `sys.path` in the Python text, modify the PYTHONPATH environment variable in the bash script.  It's easier, and is the preferred way to affect the import path anyway.

An example of how to set the path:

```
SCRIPT_DIR=/somepath/to/scripts/folder
cd $SCRIPT_DIR/eod

export PYTHONPATH=$SCRIPT_DIR
python_cmd='import settings as st; 
            print " ".join(st.foo())'
```

I also have to say, this seems like an odd way to glue components together, but I don't have enough information to recommend a better way.

Comment: Sorry to be a pain. but could you post a few lines to show how I can use `PYTHONPATH` instead? - thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Because the python command is enclosed in single quotes, `$SCRIPT_DIR` is not expanded. Try this:

```
python_cmd='import sys;
            sys.path.append("'$SCRIPT_DIR'");
            import settings as st; 
            print " ".join(st.foo())'
```

That said, I would go with the answer that modifies `PYTHONPATH`.