# How can I check if a string is in an array without iterating over the elements?

Tags: bash

Is there a way of checking if a string exists in an array of strings - without iterating through the array?

For example, given the script below, how I can correctly implement it to test if the value stored in variable $test exists in $array?

```
array=('hello' 'world' 'my' 'name' 'is' 'perseus')

#pseudo code
$test='henry'
if [$array[$test]]
   then
      do something
   else
      something else
fi
```

**Note**

I am using bash 4.1.5

Comment: I'm 100% positive an identical question already exists here. Haven't found it yet, though.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3685970/bash-check-if-an-array-contains-a-value

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: this may be the one you are referring to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3685970/bash-check-if-an-array-contains-a-value However, I don't like the solution for two reasons: 1. It involves iterating over the array, 2. A custom function must be written. I would prefer to use 'inbuilt' bash function(s)

Comment: @HomunculusReticulli Oh. If you want only builtins, the answer is "no, you can't do that" -- and you should have specified it in your question.

Comment: ...well, let's be clearer -- you can't come up with a non-iterative solution _without using associative arrays_.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: Not sure how I could have made my self more clear in the question. I stated: **without iterating through the array** the solution you offered does involve iterating through the array - if there is no inbuilt way of doing this, then that solution will have to do.

Comment: Not without iterating, but it is a very simple function to make: `lookup() { s="$1"; shift; for i; do [[ "$s" = "$i" ]] && return 0; done; return 1; }`

Comment: @HomunculusReticulli "More clear" would have been putting it in the title. Where it is, now.

Comment: While I can see why you might not want to iterate, I can't imagine why you'd want to avoid functions. They're part of well-structured code.

Comment: @DennisWilliamson: I'm new to bash (as you can prob. tell from some of my questions), so I want to use as many of the intrinsic functionality/features as possible, before resorting to "rolling my own" - which will invariably be more buggy.

Comment: @HomunculusReticulli what solution to this did you use ? I feel like I am missing that magic duh one liner for this and I definitely don`t see it here .

Comment: @CharlesDuffy stop declaring whats "Not Possible" it`s particularly un helpful and much different then saying "I don`t know how to do it ".

Comment: @JamesAndino, there are only so many ways to do O(1) lookups included in bash's implementation. (Your own answer doesn't exercise any of them, and so is in fact iterative). "Not possible" _does_ make some assumptions, when spoken about a continually-evolving language, but I'm still willing to call the ground I stand on fairly solid. (Building and applying a regex is another approach I hadn't thought of -- but while the application of a previously-compiled regular expression is non-iterative, building the regex from an array is also an iterative process).

Comment: i just have this buggards feeling there is a way to do this in a one liner every one forgot about

Comment: @JamesAndino, there may well be a one-liner we haven't collectively thought of, but a one-liner that isn't iterative in nature (even by way of a parameter expansion that loops)? I'd literally place money on its nonexistence.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

With bash 4, the closest thing you can do is use associative arrays.

```
declare -A map
for name in hello world my name is perseus; do
  map["$name"]=1
done
```

...which does the *exact* same thing as:

```
declare -A map=( [hello]=1 [my]=1 [name]=1 [is]=1 [perseus]=1 )
```

...followed by:

```
tgt=henry
if [[ ${map["$tgt"]} ]] ; then
  : found
fi
```

Comment: But strictly speaking (despite of the name) an "associative array" is not an array, but a hash table. For a pure array there is no alternative to expecting half of the items on average to find out whether a specific item is present in the array. The other alternative would be sorting the array (a real array this time) and doing a binary search. Then you would have to inspect at most log2(number_of_items).

Comment: @U.Windl, bash doesn't _have_ things that are pure arrays. Numerically-indexed "arrays" are _also_ maps in bash; they're just maps where the only allowed keys are integers. (That's why they're allowed to be sparse, and why `arr=( [1500]="hi" )` is just as memory-efficient as `arr=( [0]="hi" )`)

Comment: Didn't know that works with `declare -a` arrays; I thought it requires `declare -A` arrays, thus switching to associative arrays (hash table).

Comment: @U.Windl, regular `declare -a` arrays are absolutely sparse (and implemented as hash tables under the hood). Try it yourself.

Answer (score 9):

There will always *technically* be iteration, but it can be relegated to the shell's underlying array code. [Shell expansions](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) offer an abstraction that hide the implementation details, and avoid the necessity for an explicit loop within the shell script.

Handling word boundaries for this use case is easier with *fgrep*, which has a built-in facility for handling whole-word fixed strings. The regular expression match is harder to get right, but the example below works with the provided corpus.

#### External Grep Process

```
array=('hello' 'world' 'my' 'name' 'is' 'perseus')
word="world"
if echo "${array[@]}" | fgrep --word-regexp "$word"; then
    : # do something
fi
```

#### Bash Regular Expression Test

```
array=('hello' 'world' 'my' 'name' 'is' 'perseus')
word="world"
if [[ "${array[*]}" =~ (^|[^[:alpha:]])$word([^[:alpha:]]|$) ]]; then
    : # do something
fi
```

Comment: "Always" is a bit strong. Associative array lookups are O(1), not O(n).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy O(1) at best [depending on the underlying implementation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_array#Comparison).

Answer (score 4):

You can use an associative array since you're using Bash 4.

```
declare -A array=([hello]= [world]= [my]= [name]= [is]= [perseus]=)

test='henry'
if [[ ${array[$test]-X} == ${array[$test]} ]]
then
    do something
else
    something else
fi
```

The parameter expansion substitutes an "X" if the array element is unset (but doesn't if it's null). By doing that and checking to see if the result is different from the original value, we can tell if the key exists regardless of its value.

Comment: Think I beat you by... 25 seconds? :)

Comment: @DennisWilliamson: This is the kind of approach I was hoping for. Will this work for any bash array. See my previous question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11395776/bash-string-interpolation) to see how I am building my array. If your solution works for all bash array types (can't see why not), then this is my preferred solution.

Comment: @HomunculusReticulli: It only works for associative arrays (or regular arrays if you're testing for the presence of a numeric index).

Comment: @HomunculusReticulli: I would write the whole thing in Python.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: You did beat me slightly, but you're using the dreaded iteration to build the initial array. ;-)

Comment: This is completely pedantic, but I want to point out that associative arrays still perform iteration at the implementation level. The shell programmer just doesn't have to manually implement the indexing operation. :)

Comment: @CodeGnome, eh? They're implemented with hash tables.

Comment: In my case, I _had_ to assign a value: `[hello]=0` worked whereas `[hello]=` did not.

Comment: @Jens: What happened without the value? What version of Bash?

Comment: @DennisWilliamson: that’s with bash v5.1.16: elements `["foo"]=` would fail the lookup `[[ ${array["$test"]} ]]`.

Comment: @Jens: That's a different test. In mine, the `-X` sets a default if the element is unset.

Answer (score 3):

```
array=('hello' 'world' 'my' 'name' 'is' 'perseus')
regex="^($(IFS=\|; echo "${array[*]}"))$"

test='henry'
[[ $test =~ $regex ]] && echo "found" || echo "not found"
```

Comment: Build the regex from the array, and I think you'd have a winner here.

Comment: @Charles-Duffy: Updated with the regex

Comment: Not particularly generalized as-is -- need to escape any array contents during expansion, lest the array contain anything that doesn't match itself directly as a regex. One way to do this, though involving some performance hit: `requote() { sed 's/[^^]/[&]/g; s/\^/\\^/g' <<< "$1"; }`

Answer (score 2):

Reading your post I take it that you don't just want to know if a string exists in an array (as the title would suggest) but to know if that string actually correspond to an element of that array. If this is the case please read on.

I found a way that seems to work fine .

Useful if you're stack with bash 3.2 like I am (but also tested and working in bash 4.2):

```
array=('hello' 'world' 'my' 'name' 'is' 'perseus')
IFS=:     # We set IFS to a character we are confident our 
          # elements won't contain (colon in this case)

test=:henry:        # We wrap the pattern in the same character

# Then we test it:
# Note the array in the test is double quoted, * is used (@ is not good here) AND 
# it's wrapped in the boundary character I set IFS to earlier:
[[ ":${array[*]}:" =~ $test ]] && echo "found! :)" || echo "not found :("
not found :(               # Great! this is the expected result

test=:perseus:      # We do the same for an element that exists
[[ ":${array[*]}:" =~ $test ]] && echo "found! :)" || echo "not found :("
found! :)               # Great! this is the expected result

array[5]="perseus smith"    # For another test we change the element to an 
                            # element with spaces, containing the original pattern.

test=:perseus:
[[ ":${array[*]}:" =~ $test ]] && echo "found!" || echo "not found :("
not found :(               # Great! this is the expected result

unset IFS        # Remember to unset IFS to revert it to its default value
```

### Let me explain this:

This workaround is based on the principle that `"${array[*]}"` (note the double quotes and the asterisk) expands to the list of elements of array separated by the first character of IFS.

1. Therefore we have to set IFS to whatever we want to use as boundary (a colon in my case):

   ```
   IFS=:
   ```
2. Then we wrap the element we are looking for in the same character:

   ```
   test=:henry:
   ```
3. And finally we look for it in the array. Take note of the rules I followed to do the test (they are all mandatory): the array is double quoted, * is used (@ is not good) AND it's wrapped in the boundary character I set IFS to earlier:

   ```
   [[ ":${array[*]}:" =~ $test ]] && echo found || echo "not found :("
   not found :(
   ```
4. If we look for an element that exists:

   ```
   test=:perseus:
   [[ ":${array[*]}:" =~ $test ]] && echo "found! :)" || echo "not found :("
   found! :)
   ```
5. For another test we can change the last element 'perseus' for 'perseus smith' (element with spaces), just to check if it's a match (which shouldn't be):

   ```
   array[5]="perseus smith"
   test=:perseus:
   [[ ":${array[*]}:" =~ $test ]] && echo "found!" || echo "not found :("
   not found :(
   ```

   Great!, this is the expected result since "perseus" by itself is not an element anymore.
6. Important!: Remember to unset IFS to revert it to its default value (unset) once you're done with the tests:

   ```
   unset IFS
   ```

So so far this method seems to work, you just have to be careful and choose a character for IFS that you are sure your elements won't contain.

Hope it helps anyone!

Regards,
Fred

Comment: I know I'm late to the party, but I'd like to add that the "[ascii unit separator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_separator)" is a good candidate for the IFS to use :-)  That is exactly what this non-printable character was invented for.  To type it in vim press Ctrl+V followed by 031.  I like to assign it to a readonly variable and use that when I need it.

Answer (score 2):

In most cases, the following would work. Certainly it has restrictions and limitations, but easy to read and understand.

```
if [ "$(echo " ${array[@]} " | grep " $test ")" == "" ]; then
    echo notFound
else
    echo found
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of iterating over the array elements it is possible to use parameter expansion to delete the specified string as an array item (for further information and examples see [Messing with arrays in bash](http://floyd-n-milan.blogspot.de/2007/09/messing-with-arrays-in-bash.html) and [Modify every element of a Bash array without looping](https://web.archive.org/web/20101114051536/http://codesnippets.joyent.com/posts/show/1826)).

```
(
set -f
export IFS=""

test='henry'
test='perseus'

array1=('hello' 'world' 'my' 'name' 'is' 'perseus')
#array1=('hello' 'world' 'my' 'name' 'is' 'perseusXXX' 'XXXperseus')

# removes empty string as array item due to IFS=""
array2=( ${array1[@]/#${test}/} )

n1=${#array1[@]}
n2=${#array2[@]}

echo "number of array1 items: ${n1}"
echo "number of array2 items: ${n2}"
echo "indices of array1: ${!array1[*]}"
echo "indices of array2: ${!array2[*]}"

echo 'array2:'
for ((i=0; i < ${#array2[@]}; i++)); do 
   echo "${i}: '${array2[${i}]}'"
done

if [[ $n1 -ne $n2 ]]; then
   echo "${test} is in array at least once! "
else
   echo "${test} is NOT in array! "
fi
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
q=( 1 2 3 )
[ "${q[*]/1/}" = "${q[*]}" ] && echo not in array || echo in array 
#in array
[ "${q[*]/7/}" = "${q[*]}" ] && echo not in array || echo in array 
#not in array
```

Comment: This answer is both iterative (how do you think `${foo[@]/bar/}` works?) and inaccurate (not distinguishing between `(1 "2 3" 4)` and `(1 2 3 4)`)

Comment: The replacement happens per array entry then concats them instead of concats them and does a replacement, I checked ( thats not to say this is not a terrible way to do this ) .

Comment: Correct -- replaces per entry, then concats. So, if you're trying to test whether `2` is an entry, you wouldn't want `2 3` to be modified, which in this case it would be.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash

test="name"

array=('hello' 'world' 'my' 'yourname' 'name' 'is' 'perseus')
nelem=${#array[@]}
[[ "${array[0]} " =~ "$test " ]] || 
[[ "${array[@]:1:$((nelem-1))}" =~ " $test " ]] || 
[[ " ${array[$((nelem-1))]}" =~ " $test" ]] && 
echo "found $test" || echo "$test not found"
```

Just treat the expanded array as a string and check for a substring, but to isolate the first and last element to ensure they are not matched as part of a lesser-included substring, they must be tested separately.

Comment: You can super easily have false positives with this and if your array had word boundaries in an entry you could`t even craft a regex  you could be sure worked

Comment: That ought to tighten it up a bit.

Comment: Could you walk through ```[[ "${array[@]}" =~ "${i:0:$((${#test}))}" ]]``` , where is the i coming from ?

Comment: Should be no i in the present answer. I tested with a loop and without. Copied the wrong line :p

Comment: Now Im really gonna bug you ...  ```q=( 2 'x x' 3 ); [[ "${q[@]}" =~ " x " ]] && echo ok # ok``` , but don`t feel bad I've been up 2 days straight figuring every stupid thing about bash I can .

Comment: Touche~  That case I grant you will produce a substring match of 'x x'. The regex solution is the only loop free way to prevent against all corner cases, but it you are working with multi-line solutions, you might as well use a loop: `for i in "${array[@]}"; do test "${i:0:$((${#test}))}" == "$test" && echo "found: $i"; done`

Comment: If I put `test="hello"`, The output is wrong "hello not found"

Comment: @CalvinDuyCanhTran - remove the spaces from `[[ "${array[@]}" =~ " $test " ]]` to make `[[ "${array[@]}" =~ "$test" ]]` to match the string without whitespace.

Comment: @CalvinDuyCanhTran - thank you for catching that. The first and last element of the array must be treated separately (they will have no leading and trailing space, respectively)

Answer (score 0):

```
if ! grep -q "$item" <<< "$itemlist" ;  then .....
```

Should work fine.

Comment: Welcome to SO, Could you add more explanation to your answer please.

Comment: But grep will always inspect all items, even if you don't see it!

Answer (score 0):

for simple use cases I use something like this

```sh
array=( 'hello' 'world' 'I' 'am' 'Joe' )
word=$1

[[ " ${array[*]} " =~ " $word " ]] && echo "$word is in array!"
```

Note the spaces around `"`. This works as long as there are no spaces in the array values and the input doesn't match more values at once, like `word='hello world'`. If there are, you'd have to play with `$IFS` on top of that.